# Is it possible to create .xcarchive or .ipa with older versions of OS X?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

A customer can't manage to upload an iOS app to a private store because it doesn't support IPAs compiled with Xcode 7.3 running on Mac OS X 10.11.5. He requested me to recompile app using Xcode 7.2.x running on Mac OS X 10.10.x. Now, I downloaded and installed Xcode 7.2.1 and managed to recompile and build a new IPA, but I can't downgrade to OS X 10.10.x.

Is there any solution to this so-called "issue"?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think OS X has any influence on the built iPA. Xcode itself should contain the whole compiler-chain necessary to build it. So if you have 7.2.x running, it should work fine.

Comment: True. there will be no influence.